# Should we reset the session variables to null on web application logout?

Tags: java

Httpsession is per browser.Ideally should we reset the session variables on logout otherwise it will always be available for that Browser even user login again.Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just invalidate the session by calling [`HttpSession.invalidate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29) which will clear all the attributes as well as destroy the session itself.

Comment: Thanks adarshr.So bottomline is all session variables should  be cleared before logout. How we do it its a different story. Like the one you told HttpSession.invalidate()

Comment: Yes, just calling `invalidate()` will unbind (clear) all session attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reset all session variables. You just need to call [`session.invalidate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) and servlet framework will take care of the rest.

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case but the link you've provided is to a really legacy (1.2) version of J2EE API.